# About immutable update pattern of objects: newObject=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

demo here:

```js
let objectTest={
 a:"one",
  b:"two",
  c:"three"
}

let newObject = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objectTest))

console.log("hello, I am a new object: ", newObject)
console.log("newObject === objectTest: ", newObject === objectTest)
```

Is it okay to make an immutable copy of an object like that: newObject=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object))?

Just to grab the main properties of the object -the one that appears on the console.log().

Can we consider this transformation an immutable one?

From my demo I would say yes,since it seem to really create a new object.

Comment: New object, yes, but have you tried your technique with Date objects, or Map objects or .....

Comment: @RayToal thanks for your comment, I would use this technique just for plain objects like the one in the demo

Comment: The object is new, yes, or at least I'd be shocked if an implementation attempted an optimization in which the result was the same object! ([This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) does says a new object is constructed from a string). Just curious, though, what do you mean my immutable? Are you asking whether a copy is guaranteed by the language definition? (The resulting object from `JSON.parse` is not immutable.) I can check the ECMAScript definition to be sure.

Comment: Looks like you are good: [Official documentation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-json.parse) _does_ say object creation takes place:

Comment: @RayToal I mean immutable like in the case of not altering the original object after having created a copy, okay thanks for the feedback about the official documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, it is; [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) creates a new object every time